# freezed how to assign my own JsonConverter on top level model?

Tags: flutter, jsonserializer, jsonconvert, freezed

I have freezed model (simplified):

```
part 'initial_data_model.freezed.dart';
part 'initial_data_model.g.dart';

@freezed
class InitialDataModel with _$InitialDataModel {
  const factory InitialDataModel() = Data;

  const factory InitialDataModel.loading() = Loading;

  const factory InitialDataModel.error([String? message]) = Error;

  factory InitialDataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$InitialDataModelFromJson(json);
}
```

documentation says how to assign custom converters on fields but not on model itself

I got json from backend and somewhere in api_provider I do
`return InitialDataModel.fromJson(json);`
I have no control on json structure, there aren't "runtimeType" and other stupid redundant things

when I want to create a model from json I call `fromJson` I'm having this

```
flutter: CheckedFromJsonException
Could not create `InitialDataModel`.
There is a problem with "runtimeType".
Invalid union type "null"!
```

ok, again
I have `api_provider`

```
final apiProvider = Provider<_ApiProvider>((ref) => _ApiProvider(ref.read));

class _ApiProvider {
  final Reader read;

  _ApiProvider(this.read);

  Future<InitialDataModel> fetchInitialData() async {
    final result = await read(repositoryProvider).send('/initial_data');
    return result.when(
      (json) => InitialDataModel.fromJson(json),
      error: (e) => InitialDataModel.error(e),
    );
  }
}
```

you may see I'm trying to create `InitialDataModel` from json

this line throws an error I mentioned above

I don't understand how to create InitialDataModel from json, now in my example it's just empty model, there are no fields

`(json) => InitialDataModel.fromJson(json),`
`json` here is Map, it shows an error even if I pass simple empty map `{}` instead of real json object

Comment: do you use the `serializable` package for generating the `fromJson` method?

Comment: And why do you need a custom converter for the whole model? It should be sufficient to annotate every non-primitive field with a custom converter

Comment: you need to add  `json_serializable` to your `pubspec` `dev_dependencies`. This package will generate the required code for json conversion if you have the `fromJson` factory constructor in your freezed class. And your non-primitive fields have to be annotated with the custom json-converters

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your types. The conversion only works with primitive types like int, string, double or with annotated non-primitives. So you have to write a json-converter for `CountryModel` and for `CityModel` and annotate these fields accordingly.

Comment: which type has the `json` variable you want to convert? `String` or `Map<String, dynamic>`? If it is `String` you have to convert it first https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use the correct constructor instead of **_$InitialDataModelFromJson**. Example:

```dart
@freezed
class InitialDataModel with _$InitialDataModel {
  const factory InitialDataModel() = Data;

  ...

  factory InitialDataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data.fromJson(json);
}
```

The drawback of course is that you can only use the fromJson when you're sure you have the correct json, which isn't great. I actually wouldn't recommend this way because it leaves to the caller the burden of checking the validity and calling the correct constructor.

---

Another solution, maybe the best, is to follow the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#fromjson---classes-with-multiple-constructors) and create a custom converter, even though this would require you to have two separated classes.

---

Otherwise you could chose a different approach and separate the data class from the union, so you'll have a union used just for the state of the request and a data class for the success response:

```dart
@freezed
class InitialDataModel with _$InitialDataModel {
  factory InitialDataModel(/* here go your attributes */) = Data;

  factory InitialDataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$InitialDataModelFromJson(json);
}

@freezed
class Status with _$Status {
  const factory Status.success(InitialDataModel model) = Data;
  const factory Status.loading() = Loading;
  const factory Status.error([String? message]) = Error;
}
```

and then

```dart
[...]
    return result.when(
      (json) => Status.success(InitialDataModel.fromJson(json)),
      error: (e) => Status.error(e),
    );
[...]
```

Comment: oooo man, I saved my life!!!! I spent whole day on it and you're totally right, I just changed `=> _$InitialDataModelFromJson(json);` to `=> _$Data.fromJson(json);` and it's working now! my real code much much complex then this example but I didn't change any extra lines, the reason was in constructor as you said, thanks a lot

Comment: That's great! I improved my answer anyway to add some opinions and another solution in case someone else needs this

Comment: i got some issue when implement nested object response with one dart , i only can work with separate file but the documentation determine we can on just 1 file i mean `const factory Data.root` and `const factory Data.child` . still on problem

Comment: @YogiArifWidodo too little information sorry, please open a new question (also, I haven't played with Dart for some months, so I'm not sure I can help)